# Asynchronous processing xml download xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a serious problem in the matter of dowload I do not know what I do to solve this question and came this idea of ​​asynchronous processing. How to do this in xamarin to do a dowload of an xml file?

Comment: What have you tried allready? Share some code and we can chime in helping you finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
  string url = "http://123qwe/hub/feed";
  string data = await client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

I managed to do this with, now how do I return and save the file in the folder following this command? Anybody know

Comment: DownloadStringAsync will return your data as a string - see my edit.  Then you can use normal file I/O to save the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43141332/5779818 I have created a sample here

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Gave error in this line, can be something of conversion